# Access SQL: Combining SELECT and USER INPUT

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm creating a form in Access where users can select a commodity out of a list of possible commodities, and then a query calculates the average price of the selected commodity.

The input field for the user is a list (**List147**). Let's say the user selects Copper, then I want the average to be returned for Copper. The prices of all commodities are in a table called **CommMaterial**. The snip below shows what the table looks like.

[image]

I'm fairly new at SQL and am not sure how to code this. It appears as if the `SELECT` statement needs to be dynamic, but I don't know how to do this. I envision something like this:

```
SELECT AVG(CommMaterial.[Forms]![NameForm]![List147])
FROM CommMaterial;
```

Comment: You are right about it needing to be dynamic. Ultimately this seems like maybe your schema isn't the greatest. A table that is set up like `DateComm | Metal | Price` would allow you this drop down flexibility without having to monkey with dynamic sql.

Comment: @JNevill That's definitely an option, I'm just wondering if it's possible to do it via a dynamic query.

Comment: I just added an answer that may keep you from needing to go the dynamic SQL route by using a UNION query to reformat the schema of the table. Someone that is better at Access Forms might have a reasonable way of doing the dynamic SQL stuff, but I remember VBA and pain the last time I built something like that in Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep from dynamic sql and VBA, You could use some SQL to get your table into a slightly more query-able format:

```
SELECT DateComm, 'Copper' as Metal, Copper as Price FROM CommMaterial
UNION ALL
SELECT DateComm, 'Nickel' as Metal, Nickel as Price FROM CommMaterial
UNION ALL
SELECT DateComm, 'Aluminum' as Metal, Aluminum as Price FROM CommMaterial;
```

Which will give you a result set with three columns:

```
DateComm | Metal | Price
```

You could save that as a query `qry_CommMaterial` and then your SQL would be:

```
SELECT Avg(Price) FROM qry_CommMaterial WHERE metal = [Forms]![NameForm]![List147];
```

You could also just force it all into one big statement too:

```
 SELECT Avg(Price) 
 FROM (
         SELECT DateComm, 'Copper' as Metal, Copper as Price FROM CommMaterial
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DateComm, 'Nickel' as Metal, Nickel as Price FROM CommMaterial
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DateComm, 'Aluminum' as Metal, Aluminum as Price FROM CommMaterial) as subUnion
 WHERE metal = [Forms]![NameForm]![List147];
```

Comment: Thank you! The commodity table has many more commodities though, so I probably would need to create a line for each commodity.  I'll play around and see what works best in terms of performance etc.

Comment: This is a good way to go about it if your `CommMaterial` table's columns never change.  You will have to edit your `UNION` query appropriately if it does ever change.  If you wanted it truly dynamic in Access, then you will have to use VBA to parse through the columns, unioning each.

Comment: That's the downside: that it's likely that you would add more commodities in the future, which means you have to add columns to keep up with the business, and then add to the UNION statement... this is why it's not the greatest table schema, but I totally get not wanting to change it. Sometimes it's just easier to deal with the pivoted data with a Union and call it a day.